# linker error for a static member of class

Tags: c++, linker-errors, static-members

I am trying to find a solution to a linker error for a static member of a class

Here is the code:

```
//node.h
class Node{

public:

static vector<Node*> nodePointers; //i will use these pointers to access multiple objects of the same class
int id;
int a;
int b;

friend int add(Node*,int);

void itsMyLife(int);
Node();
};

//node.cpp
void Node::itsMyLife(int x){

int answer=0;
if(nodePointers[x]->a<100){
    answer=add(this,nodePointers[x]->id);
}

cout<<"Answer in node "<<id<<" is "<<answer<<endl;

}

int add(Node* x, int y){

return x->a+x->nodePointers[y]->b;
}

//main.cpp
int* myInts=new int[10];
vector<int*> intVectors;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    intVectors[i]=&myInts[i];

Node* myNodes=new Node[2];

for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    myNodes[0].nodePointers[i]=&myNodes[i];

myNodes[0].id=0;
myNodes[0].a=10;
```

When I compile and link it gives me the error:

Undefined reference to Node::nodePointers

Why is that I get this error? I will be grateful for your help. Thanks again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574407/673730 - the "static data members must be defined outside the class in a single translation unit" part

Answer (score 0):

Static class members should be initialized **(1)once (2)outside** of the class definition. Usually the best place for this is relevant .cpp file.

In other words you should add something like this to your node.cpp:

```
vector<Node*> Node::nodePointers;
```

Comment: Is there a point to the ` = vector<Node*>()` part?

Comment: Thanks leo, it removed the undefined reference error. Any idea why the above code might cause a "segmentation fault"?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore good point. Java habbit. Fixed.

Comment: @user2105632 probably you have a crash due to that you haven't allocated enough space for elements in `intVectors`. See docs on how to o this here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/